# How to centered button(ok) in JOptionPane

Tags: java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfAyZ.png)

Here is code, as you can see the button is not centered.

```
login.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(true){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successfully login",
                            null, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                }
                else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No such an account, please register a new account",
                            null, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
    });
    }
```

Comment: This is the default behaviour. If you need something else, then create your own custom dialog.

Comment: If it were centred, it would look ugly as it would be too close to the label. Also, should that not say "Login successful"?

Comment: For me, using [CrossPlatformLookAndFeel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html#available) with Java 8 on Windows 10, the button **is** centered. What platform are you on? (Looks like MacOS from your image.) What look-and-feel are you using? What Java version are you using?

Comment: @Abra Hi, my platform is macOS. I just use the default setting and I do not sure if I used look-and-feel since I was new to java swing. Also I just use the java 8. If i need to use look-and-feel, could you tell how to use it? Thanks